# MySQL stored procedure syntax IF else

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Guys i can not find solution for this problem , its always giving syntax error what ever i have tried ... can you just cast a look for me , thanks

```
create procedure SP_Insert(in MatchIDP int,in TipID int, in User int)
begin

if exists(
select BetSlipID from betslips where MatchID = MatchIDP and UserID = User)
(
   update Betslips set TipID = 2
)
else
(
   insert into Betslips (MatchID,TipID , UserID) value (MatchIDP,TipID,User)
)
end if
end
```

I just want to check if data exists in table before i do insert , and i can not use "On duplicate key update" because my primary key does not mean anything , its table where i put in 2-3 foreign keys ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `IF` syntax is incorrect.  It should be:

```
delimiter ;;

create procedure SP_Insert(in MatchIDP int,in TipID int, in User int)
begin

if exists(
  select * from betslips where MatchID = MatchIDP and UserID = User
) then
  update Betslips set TipID = 2; -- where ?
else
  insert into Betslips (MatchID,TipID , UserID) values (MatchIDP, TipID, User);
end if;

end;;
```

However, if you will never permit duplicate `(MatchID, UserID)` entries in your `Betslips`, why not define a `UNIQUE` constraint across those columns and then use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
ALTER TABLE Betslips ADD UNIQUE INDEX (MatchID, UserID);

INSERT INTO Betslips (MatchID, TipID, UserID) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TipID = 2;
```

Comment: thanks for answer mate , idea is that i never have one user to bet on same game more then once , that is reason why i am checking if that data exists

Comment: @Veljko89: Then I'd go with my second suggestion, of defining an appropriate `UNIQUE` constraint and then using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: But `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` i can not check `MatchID` and `UserID` combo exists , and that is thing what matters to me... right?

Comment: @Veljko89: That's exactly what it will do if you define the `UNIQUE` constraint as advised in my answer.

Comment: hmm in that case ill google a bit more about it ... thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Insert (IN MatchIDP INT, IN TipID INT, IN USER INT)
BEGIN
        DECLARE existing INT DEFAULT NULL;

        SELECT BetSlipID
        INTO   existing
        FROM   betslips
        WHERE  MatchID = MatchIDP
        AND    UserID = USER;

        IF existing is not null THEN
            UPDATE Betslips SET TipID = 2;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO Betslips (MatchID, TipID, UserID)
            VALUES (MatchIDP, TipID, USER);
        END IF;

END
```

Comment: @eggyal Then you can easily add an equal sign to `existing > 0` => `existing >= 0`. I changed the condition, checking against `null`.

Comment: Okay, what if there's a matching record with `BetSlipID=NULL` (perhaps not possible in the OP's data model, but nevertheless this is a bit sloppy... surely `EXISTS` was a more correct test?)