# Unable to execute "IF EXISTS" query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a SQL query, but something is messed up and I can't get below query to check if the data exists or not in the specified table.

**The code I have is:**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT brth_day FROM sms.birthdaycheck WHERE brth_day = '2015-02-10')
THEN
  BEGIN
    UPDATE sms.birthdaycheck SET cnt = 1 WHERE brth_day = '2015-02-10'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sms.birthdaycheck(cnt,brth_day) VALUES (1,'2015-02-10')
  END
END IF;
```

Comment: Do not add comments, edit the question. Your code is not PHP. Use the right tags.

Comment: what `database engine` you are using?

Comment: Didn't you get that warning, `Your post only containes code, please add some text`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited solution :**

```
 delimiter ;;
 create procedure XYZ(...parameters...)
 begin

 if exists(
    SELECT brth_day FROM sms.birthdaycheck WHERE brth_day = '2015- 
    02-10') 
 then
    UPDATE sms.birthdaycheck SET cnt = 1 WHERE brth_day = '2015-02-10';
 else
    INSERT INTO sms.birthdaycheck(cnt,brth_day) VALUES (1,'2015-02-10');
    end if;

 end;;
```

Comment: Please go through this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334026/mysql-stored-procedure-syntax-if-else

Comment: Are you sure? According to google 1064 is a MySQL Error : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=1064+error+comes+in+which+datbase&oq=1064+error+comes+in+which+datbase&aqs=chrome..69i57.9941j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score -2):

In MySQL, if control block must used inside a function or stored procedure.
So you need to rewrite your query: